# Alta disponiblididad en cluster de Postgres XL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, cluster, postgresql-10

necesito crear un cluster de alta disponiblidad pero al momento de crear un servidor en modo standby me da problemas ya que no me deja promoverlo:

[image: Error al promover nodo]

quisiera que me ayuden en como puedo crear un cluster de alta disponibilidad o como crear el servidor standby

Segui [ese tutorial](https://programmerclick.com/article/40611219626/#:%7E:text=Postgres%2DXLEs%20un%20cl%C3%BAster,OLTP%20escribe%20negocios) para crear el cluster

Comment: Reformula la pregunta. ¿Cómo lo intentaste y cuáles son los errores específicos?

Comment: El cluster esta listo pero quiero promover un nodo de datos a maestro en caso de que el maestro original se caiga pero al momento de introducir el comando pg_ctl promote me dice que no es posible porque el servidor que quiero promover no está en modo standby

Comment: ¿Qué has probado? Añade el código a la pregunta.

Comment: ya agregue una imagen con el error que me sale he buscado en varios foros pero no se como crear un servidor standby para poder promoverlo a maestro

Comment: Lo que la documentación indica sobre el standby mode: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/standby-settings.html

Comment: acabo de crear un archivo recovery.conf pero ahora me devuelve: pg_ctl server did not promote in time, es posible adjuntar la captura de mi archivo recovery.conf?

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible y presentar que problema tienes al crear el cluster, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo (copiado y pegado), También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].